# How do I use the sender argument to figure out what UIImageView was selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sender

I have eight `UIImageViews` that I want to fade if the `UITapGestureRecognizer` that is associated with it is activated. I have the all recognizers hooked up to this `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)disableDie:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
    NSLog(@"%ld",[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag);

}
```

I thought I could do it with a loop like this:

```
- (IBAction)disableDie:(id)sender {

    for (UIImageView *numberImage in self.diceOutletArray) {
        if (numberImage == sender) {
            numberImage.alpha = 0.65;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
    NSLog(@"%ld",[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag);

}
```

But nothing happens to the `UIImageView` that was pressed, but the message's are printed. I have used the `diceOutletArray` in other loops and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sender is a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, not a `UIImageView`, and
therefore `numberImage == sender` will never be true.

Try this instead:

```
- (IBAction)disableDie:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    for (UIImageView *numberImage in self.diceOutletArray) {
        if (numberImage == sender.view) {
            numberImage.alpha = 0.65;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't actually need the loop at all though, this would work fine as well:

```
- (IBAction)disableDie:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    sender.view.alpha = 0.65;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The gesture recognizer is the sender, not the view. You should see that in the printout of `sender`. You need to get the recognizer's view (assuming that it's attached directly to its image view).

Once you have that, you don't really need to go and find another pointer to the view: you already have it. It's just called `sender.view` instead of `mumbleMumbleImageView`.

Just send `setAlpha:` to that pointer.